# Double entry process to record 401k change in value

Tags: united-states, roth-401k, double-entry

My Roth 401(k) statement shows the following fields:

- Payroll Contributions (including employer match)
- Change in Value
- Dividends
- Expenses

In double-entry accounting, is the "Change in Value" income or equity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Equity, specifically "Accumulated other comprehensive income" or "Revaluation Reserve".

https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/available-for-sale-security.asp